# Cannot reach device/ip when started by docker, but from shell inside the same container

Tags: python, docker

I wan't to check whether a server/device is reachable or not, by using a python script running inside docker.

I'm using python 3.7.

The script looks like the following snipped (scriped down)

```
import platform
import subprocess
import asyncio

from argparse import ArgumentParser
from time import sleep
from models.configuration import Configuration


parser = ArgumentParser()

# device ip or hostname
parser.add_argument(
    '-d', '--device',
    type=str,
    required=True,
)


async def main():
    args = parser.parse_args()
    configuration = Configuration(args)  # the configuration object stores the arguments

    param = '-n' if platform.system().lower() == 'windows' else '-c'

    while True:
        result = subprocess.call(['ping', param, '1', configuration.device])
        print(f'## {result}')
        # TODO: result = 0 => success, result > 0 => failure
        sleep(5)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.7

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY . .
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requierments.txt

ENTRYPOINT [ "python3", "./main.py", "-d IP_OR_HOSTNAME" ]
```

I also tried `CMD` instead of `ENTRYPOINT`.

I build and start the container with the following commands

```
docker build -t my-app .
docker run -it --network host --name my-app my-app
```

Running the script by docker, the ping command exits with the exit code 2 (`Name or Service not known`).
When I start the script from the shell inside the container (`python3 /usr/src/app/main.py -d IP_OR_HOSTNAME`), the device is reachable (exit code 0).
As far as I know I have to use the network mode `host`.

Any ideas why the script cannot reach the device when launched by docker, but from shell inside the container?

(I am open to suggestions for a better title)

Comment: In the Dockerfile, it looks like you pass `"-d IP_OR_HOSTNAME"` as a single word with an embedded space; does it help to remove the space `"-dIP"` or to use two words `"-d", "IP"`?  Does `print(repr(configuration.device))` show the same thing in both cases?

Comment: @David Maze: `"-d IP_OR_HOSTNAME"` produces a leading space, but using `"-dIP_OR_HOSTNAME"` and `"-d", "IP_OR_HOSTNAME"` doesn't. Using one of the other ways works. Thanks! Feel free to write an answer, than I will mark it as the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The various Dockerfile commands that run commands have two forms.  In [shell form](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#shell-form-entrypoint-example), without special punctuation, Docker internally runs a shell and the command is broken into words using that shell's normal rules.  If you write the command as a JSON array, though, it uses an [exec form](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#exec-form-entrypoint-example) and the command is executed with exactly the words you give it.

In your command:

```sh
ENTRYPOINT [ "python3", "./main.py", "-d IP_OR_HOSTNAME" ]
```

There are three words in the command: `python3`, `./main.py`, and then as a single argument `-d IP_OR_HOSTNAME` including an embedded space.  When the Python `argparse` module sees this, it interprets it as a single option with the `-d` short option and text afterwards, and so the value of the "hostname" option is  `IP_OR_HOSTNAME` *including a leading space*.

There are various alternate ways to "spell" this that will have the effect you want:

```sh
# Split "-d" and the argument into separate words
ENTRYPOINT ["python3", "./main.py", "-d", "IP_OR_HOSTNAME"]

# Remove the space between "-d" and its option
ENTRYPOINT ["python3", "./main.py", "-dIP_OR_HOSTNAME"]

# Use the shell form to parse the command into words "normally"
ENTRYPOINT python3 ./main.py -d IP_OR_HOSTNAME
```